# WebSphere console config setting?

Tags: websphere

I don't have access to a WebSphere console, but I need to check if encryption is enabled between the console and appserver connection. The docs I have come across are almost all console related, and I am unable to find what I need. Where would I be able to find this config file setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for WCInboundAdminSecure : it should be located in :
{WAS_HOME}/config/cells/{your cell}/nodes/{your node}/servers/{your server}/server.xml

Comment: Hi and thanks! that is what I am looking for but I still missing something. So if I understand you correctly, SSL between appserver and console is configured from the server initiating the connection? Is there a config file on the appserver? Also what documentation are you finding this info?

Comment: There is several tools to configure websphere, admin console is one of them, there is also wsadmin which is command-line for example. All of these tools are using web services that are exposed through the WCInboundAdmin and/or WCInboundAdminSecure channels. Be careful it is slightly different if you are using standalone websphere installation or network installation (cluster...). I'm sorry to say that these kind of info is quite difficult to find as IBM share knowledge only through their training program. This is based on my own experience.